# Git switch tree

Tags: git, tree

I am trying to build [QuakeJS](https://github.com/inolen/quakejs) but the ioq3 folder is empty. On GitHub it says the tree is `4f7d7bf`. How do I switch the folder to this tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ioq3 is a submodule](https://github.com/inolen/quakejs/blob/master/.gitmodules). Update submodules:

```
git submodule sync
git submodule update
```

Next time clone with submodules:

```
git clone --recursive
```